# eBay XML API returns 'Invalid job context type' error

Tags: ebay-api

I am developing eBay manager that is almost completed. Everything is running fine, like posting of data, getting order details from eBay.

Now I need to update the status of Shipping Tracking numbers, Carrier on eBay. Here I am getting error and I can't figured out what is the problem. Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Help Reference: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/CompleteSale.html

Error response:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <GetSellerTransactionsResponse
>   xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><Timestamp>2010-01-13T12:50:29.644Z<Ack>Failure<Errors><ShortMessage>Invalid
>   job context type<LongMessage>The job context object
>   is not supported by Action Service
>   Framework.<ErrorCode>21843<SeverityCode>Error<ErrorParameters
>   ParamID="0"><Value>GetSellerTransactions<ErrorParameters
>   ParamID="1"><Value>CompleteSaleRequestTypeRequestError<Version>643<Build>E643_CORE_BUNDLED_10284414_R1</GetSellerTransactionsResponse>

Comment: code file uploaded here :

http://www.go4vacation.com/completesale.zip

(very small file almost 3 kb.)

Comment: The XML you posted is not valid XML. Please try to post the actual XML, with no extra characters.

Comment: john@ :i have done the XML proper..Please review it and help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got this error when accidentally having the wrong X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME value for the call I was making.

For example, in my header I put GetSellerEvents, but my request body was using GetSellerList.

Hope that helps!

- Joe

Comment: And yes. I looked at your code. That is the exact situation, and your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar issue.  I had non-matching values in the headers and the XML; I had `AddItem` in the header, but `VerifyAddItemRequest` in the XML. (A copy and paste issue).  The XML part needs to be `AddItemRequest` in this case.

After fixing this, I made my first-ever successful item listing in the sandbox.