# Ebay Api - Adding products with php

Tags: php, web-applications, ebay-api

I'm having trouble with the eBay API, I am trying to upload my inventory to my eBay store. I have registered as a developer and read through the tutorials and examples but for some reason this wont work, here is my current XML that is generated through the database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItems xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
<Item>
<Title>Fun Novelty Routemaster Red Bus Mug</Title>
<Description><p>Fun Novelty Routemaster Red Bus Mug</p><p>If you are looking for a novelty gift thats practical and looks great, then check out our funky kitchen and ceramics range.</p><p>The range is made from dolomite ceramics and finished in a high gloss glaze. Each comes in a decorative gift box to complete the look, plus if its a kitchen item then dolomite is food and microwave safe but cannot be put in the dishwasher.</p></Description>
<PrimaryCategory><CategoryID>14899</CategoryID>
</PrimaryCategory>
<StartPrice>9.99</StartPrice>
<CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
<ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
<Country>GB</Country>
<Currency>GBP</Currency>
<DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
<ListingDuration>Days_30</ListingDuration>
<ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
<PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
<PayPalEmailAddress>info@3cheekymonkeys.co.uk</PayPalEmailAddress>
<PictureDetails><GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
</PictureDetails>
<PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
<ProductListingDetails><UPC>5055071655654</UPC>
<IncludeStockPhotoURL>true</IncludeStockPhotoURL>
<IncludePrefilledItemInformation>true</IncludePrefilledItemInformation>
<UseFirstProduct>true</UseFirstProduct>
<UseStockPhotoURLAsGallery>true</UseStockPhotoURLAsGallery>
<ReturnSearchResultOnDuplicates>true</ReturnSearchResultOnDuplicates>
</ProductListingDetails>
<Quantity>6</Quantity>
<ReturnPolicy><ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
<RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
<ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
<Description>If you are not satisfied, return the item for refund.    </Description>
<ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
</ReturnPolicy>
<ShippingDetails><ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
<ShippingServiceOptions><ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
<ShippingService>UK_RoyalMailFirstClassStandard</ShippingService>
<FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
<ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>0.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
</ShippingServiceOptions>
</ShippingDetails>
<Site>UK</Site>
</Item>
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>AUTHC CODE</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</AddItems>
```

and here is the results from ebay

```
The AddItem called failed due to the following error(s):
Error: [21843] The job context object is not supported by Action Service Framework.
```

My Headers and CURL

```
    $headers = array(
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:'.SITEID,
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:AddItem',
    'X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING:'.RESPONSE_ENCODING,
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:' . API_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL,
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:' . API_DEV_NAME,
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:' . API_APP_NAME,
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:' . API_CERT_NAME,
    'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'
);

// initialize our curl session
$session  = curl_init(API_URL);

// set our curl options with the XML request
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// execute the curl request
$responseXML = curl_exec($session);

// close the curl session
curl_close($session);

// return the response XML
return $responseXML;
```

When changing from AddItem to AddFixedPriceItemRequest the error changes to

```
 Schema XML request error: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize..
```

When running the example in the API Test Tool it wont work same results, and also when running the Test Tool with the example code provided it works until i copy that sample XML into my file and try and run the program then i get the error messages back?

Comment: Why do you not using https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php ? I would recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The html tags within the description tag breaks the xml. For a workaround you want to enclose your description using CDATA:

```
<Description><![CDATA[ <p>Fun Novelty .. put in the dishwasher.</p>]]></Description>
```

**In Detail:**

- `Error: [21843] The job context object is not supported by Action Service Framework.` seems to be provoked by a mismatch between the header and the xml.

See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13791811/2797243

- `Schema XML request error: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize..`

There can be many reasons why you are recieiving this error, but we will focus on just 2 situations:

1. You may be getting this error because the given root element in your request xml document does not match any Element Declarations in eBay Schema.

Answer Title: Error 20170 - Schema XML request error
Answer Link: https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=897

2. Another common reason is your  has HTML or XML reserved characters.  For a workaround you want to enclose your description using CDATA.

Comment: The eBayAuthToken is at the bottom of the XML.

Comment: @nats0128 the html in the descr is the problem.

Comment: Spot on, the html was breaking the xml, saved me a massive headache

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`<AddItems xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">`

to

`<AddItemsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">`

and:

`</AddItems>`

to

`</AddItemsRequest>`

Comment: Same Error, Changed what you said, even changed the Additem in the header to AddItemsRequest, and that brought back Error: [2] The API call "AddItemsRequest" is invalid or not supported in this release. @Isaac